# Excel 2013 VBA CommandBar dropdown empty

Tags: excel, vba, commandbar

I have a problem with an old Excel add-in using an xla file with some VBA code and user interface via forms, and a dll that handles communication to a server. The add-in downloads data and inserts it into the active Excel sheet. This application was written for Office 97 and is working well on all versions of Excel since that except for (some installations of) Excel 2013. Actually, the application works fine also in Excel 2013, except for one little detail. There are a few dropdowns (CommandBarComboBox) that is supposed to be loaded with some information when the sheet is loaded with data, but this doesn't work in all Excel 2013 installations. For example in my own Excel 2013 (32-bit), this happens:

Case 1: I have installed the dll in C:\Windows and the xla file in the XLStart folder of Office 2013. The dropdowns are empty.

Case 2: I have installed the dll in C:\Windows, no xla file in XLStart. Instead I open the xla file after starting Excel from the start menu (I'm running 64-bit Windows 7). After opening, I am asked if I want to enable macros in the file I've loaded. After answering yes and downloaded data, I have information in the dropdowns.

Any ideas anyone?